# How I can generate dynamic data for the parameters to test a wcf service?

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, automated-tests

I have a unit test that consume a web service and this unit test is inside a load test of a web perfomnace and load test project. so i have for example in the unit test the next method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void getUserByCity(){
       List<Users>  users = servicioWCF.getUsersByCity("Monterrey");
}
```

so what i want is find a way to pass the city in dynamically way in order that the result change for differents calls to this method made for differents virtual users of the test.

So the result will be almost the same that do the next one:

call 1(virtual user 1):

```
List<Users>  users =servicioWCF.getUsersByCity("Monterrey");
```

call 2(virtual user 2):

```
List<Users>  users =servicioWCF.getUsersByCity("Escobedo");
```

Comment: I would caution against doing something like this, primarily because your tests should be deterministic and reproducible. With the setup you described, it would be possible for one developer to see a test passing, and another user to see the *exact same test* failing.

Comment: yes you are right but anyway i need to find a way to simulate a load calling the same method but with different parameters every time.

Comment: Have you looked into [data-driven unit tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527(v=vs.120).aspx)?  This walk-through of [Passing Load Test Context Parameters to Unit Tests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2006/05/15/passing-load-test-context-parameters-to-unit-tests.aspx) may also be helpful.

Comment: thanks let me check it out!!